# mysql get result based on input percentage

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database for question as following.

```
ID  q_name  difficulty_level
1   abc     easy
2   pqr     normal
3   xyz     difficult
```

There are about 1,20,000 records in DB. Now i want to get result base on input percentage.

Let say i am going to get 20 records where 33% should easy, 33% should normal and 34% should difficult. Please check attached image for better idea. I am not getting how to make a simpler query to get result fast.

[image]

Comment: To get 33% random easy questions. First compute 33% of 20. That would be roughly 6 (or you can take 7). Now just do: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE difficulty_level = 'easy' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6` Similarly do for other difficulty levels as well. You can get all the results in a single query by doing `UNION ALL` between individual select queries.

Comment: Let's pretend that there are 20 rows. Now see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

seems you're looking for a union select

```
select ID, q_name 
FROM questions 
where difficulty_level = 'easy' 
limit (ROUND(20*33/100))

union all

select ID, q_name 
FROM questions 
where difficulty_level = 'normal' 
limit (ROUND(20*33/100))

union all

select ID, q_name 
FROM questions 
where difficulty_level = 'difficult' 
limit (ROUND(20*34/100))
```

You should also pay attention to the number of results.
As 33% of 20 ist 6.6 you have to get 6 or 7 Results.
In the example you have 34% on difficult, what means, its slieghtly preferred, so probably you want round it up.

IMHO i would prefer calculating the limit in a language you create the MySQL command 
(PHP ?)
so that you can limit on an Integer.